# Regular expression for grouping the data

Tags: javascript, regex, linux, shell, csv

I need a regular expresion to group my data inside the CSV file. I need to group the data on a particular string "PDP-TD-PDP"
My file content is given below.

```
PDP-TD-PDP
aaaaaa
bbbbbb
cccccc
dddddd
eeeeee
PDP-TD-PDP
ffffff
gggggg
hhhhhh
iiiiii
PDP-TD-PDP
jjjjjj
kkkkkk
llllll
mmmmmm
```

So my outcome should be like below, I need to group the data with each

```
1 PDP-TD-PDP
1 aaaaaa
1 bbbbbb
1 cccccc
1 dddddd
1 eeeeee
2 PDP-TD-PDP
2 ffffff
2 gggggg
2 hhhhhh
2 iiiiii
3 PDP-TD-PDP
3 jjjjjj
3 kkkkkk
3 llllll
3 mmmmmm
```

We need this requirement because for each special string "PDP-TD-PDP" we need to load content to different tables. If we have the group ID then we could easly extract from the file

Comment: What have you tried? What doesn't work?

Comment: What made you think regex was the tool for this?!

Answer (score 0):

How about just spliting string into lines and then anazyzing them?

```js
const data = `
PDP-TD-PDP

aaaaaa

bbbbbb

cccccc

dddddd

eeeeee

PDP-TD-PDP

ffffff

gggggg

hhhhhh

iiiiii

PDP-TD-PDP

jjjjjj

kkkkkk

llllll

mmmmmm`

const asignId = data => {
    const lines = data.split('\n')
    let out = ''
    let id = 0
    for (let i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
        if (/\S+/.test(lines[i])) {
            if (/PDP-TD-PDP/.test(lines[i])) id++
            out += id + ' ' + lines[i] + '\n'
        } else {
            out += lines[i] + '\n'
        }
    }
    return out
}
console.log(asignId(data))
```

Answer (score 0):

You ask for a regular expression, but in order to keep a counter you need something more or something else. If you state the language of regular expressions that you are using (for example: perl's, etc.) then a regular expression could be provided.

However, your sample test can be converted to your sample output (notice it is not CSV!) using an awk script. Let's assume your sample text is called: "sample.csv"

```
awk 'BEGIN { count=0 } { if ($1 == "PDP-TD-PDP") count++; print count, $0 }' sample.csv > sample.out
```

Then, sample.out will have the output that you asked for in your sample.
$0 contains the entire record, and $1 contains the first word.

However; as you mention you are dealing with a CSV file, you probably want an output more like:

1, ....

1, ....

2, ....

2, ....

So then, your awk script should look like:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS=",", count=0 } { if ($1 == "PDP-TD-PDP") count++; print count "," $0 }' sample.csv > sample.out
```

Notice the changes: FS set at the beginning (field separator) and the print statement changed to print a comma in between the count and the records without spaces around the comma.

If PDP-TD-PDP can appear anywhere and not just the first record, then change: ($1 == "PDP-TD-PDP") by (/PDP-TD-PDP/).